# How can I pass a String data from my service to my fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, timer

I have a service that runs a timer on the background and I want that data to be passed to my fragment to show the timer there too. If i closed my app and open it again  i want to see my edittext to show the timer. Any answer would be appreciated.

this is my service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Vibrator v;
    //private static Timer timer = new Timer();
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private static final int uniqueID = 71399;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Timer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int dur = sharedPreferences.getInt("duration", 0);

        //background timer
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(dur,    1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long dur) {
                long millis= dur;
                String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
                        //seconds
                        ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                );
                startnotif(hms);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                long n[] = {1,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000,500,1000};
                v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(n, -1);
                endnotif();
                onDestroy();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    //notification
    public void startnotif(String hms)
    {
        String noT = hms;
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setTicker("apps are blocked!");
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle("Be productive!");
        notification.setContentText(hms);
        ClickNotif();
    }

    public void endnotif(){
        notification.setContentText("00:00");
        notification.setTicker("apps are now unblocked!");
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle("You survived!");
        notification.setContentText("Apps are now unblocked!");
        ClickNotif();
    }

    public void ClickNotif(){
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
    }

}
```

and here is the fragment. I'm planning on removing the countdown timer on this fragment since I'm going use the timer on the service.

```
public class page2 extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG =   "page2";

    private Button btntest;
    private TextView timer,tv;
    private Spinner spinner, spinner2;
    public int hours, mins, duration;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_fragment,container,false);

        btntest = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        timer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Timer);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        //setting up 2 spinners
        spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String [] values = {"00","01","02","03","04","05","06"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String [] values2 = {"00","01","10","20","30","40","50","60"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values2);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        //button start
        btntest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String spin=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                hours = Integer.parseInt(spin);
                hours = hours*3600000;
                String spin2=spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                mins = Integer.parseInt(spin2);
                mins = mins*60000;
                duration = hours+mins;
                setParam(duration);
                startService(duration);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    //timer part
    public void setParam(int param){
         CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(param,    1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long param) {
                long millis= param;
                String hms= String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",

                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis))
                        //seconds
                        ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
                );
                timer.setText(hms);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setText("00:00");
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    //saving data and passing intent to service
    public void startService(int duration)
    {
        int d = duration;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Timer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("duration", d);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Intent passed and preferences saved!"+d,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use broadcastreciever to send your data to fragment

Answer (score 1):

Try EventBus library, you can send message as normal or stick event, maybe it can solve your problem :)

Comment: As much as possible I don't want to use libraries. But thanks!

Comment: Or your can use broadcaster

Comment: And the onBind is used for connecting your activity and your service, there lots of method can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can update editText in your case.

1. When you open your application you can bind to your already running service. After binding you can call methods in service to get the results. For simple bind service refer [bind service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder)
2. You can keep a shared preference and continue updating it every countdown. Whenever app opens read the shared preference and update your edittext.